# How to dump the micropython filesystem from the SPIKE Prime (and Mindstorms v4)?

Tags: powered-up, spike-prime, micropython, robot-inventor

I'm interested in tinkering with the micropython filesystem and/or firmware in the SPIKE Prime hub and was wondering:

1. How to dump the micropython filesystem from the SPIKE Prime hub?
2. Is there an online resource somewhere to download old micropython filesystems for the SPIKE Prime hub?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [rshell](https://github.com/dhylands/rshell) I've managed dump the micropython filesystem of my hub after updating it to `v1.0.03.0034-c3879ab`.

```
rshell
connect serial /dev/ttyACM0 115200
rsync -a /pyboard ~/spikefw
```

*Note: These commands are for linux.*

(I also managed to partially dump the initial version on the hub `v0.5.01.0000-42a938e`, but ran into issues with binary files as I was using [ampy](https://github.com/insighio/ampy) at the time.)

I've not found any online resources for the micropython filesystem or the firmware of the SPIKE Prime hub.

Interestingly it seems the the initial version I have `v0.5.01.0000-42a938e` is comprised of the micropython source code (*.py files) whereas the updated version `v1.0.03.0034-c3879ab` only contains pre-compiled micropython bytecode (*.mpy)

The license file included with the micropython code, and the headers in the files, state that the code is licensed under the MIT license, so I've uploaded it to my [github](https://github.com/gpdaniels/spike-prime) please feel free to PR more versions.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for sharing. It's nice that the firmware is MIT licensed.

Comment: No problem! Like I say if anyone else manages to dump their SPIKE Prime filesystem I'm happy to accept PRs into the project to compile more comprehensive history.